# Traverse the DOM to locate a specific DIV tag where IDs are not unique

Tags: jquery, parent, children

The table below is looped so I cannot rely on a unique id, I have to traverse the DOM to get the items.  I would like to report back the results from my ajax call when the CHECK button is clicked.

```
<table cellpadding="3" class="tablesorter" id="table_id">
<tr>
<td><input name="systemname" type="text" id="systemname" class="systemname" value="#rsRequestSystems.systemname#" size="50" maxlength="50">
<div class="SystemNameStatus" id="SystemNameStatus" style="color:##0000FF"></div></td>
<th class="form"><label>Location</label></th>
<td align="center"><button type="button" id="removeButton" class="fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all remove_SystemName" style="width:70px;">Remove</button>
<button type="button" id="checkButton" class="fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all check_SystemName" style="width:70px;">Check</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is my jQuery statement; right now, I'm just trying to hard code some text but ideally, I'll be returning some text from an ajax result to populate the SystemNameStatus div.  I can't seem to isolate the DIV.  I'm not comfortable with traversing the DOM yet despite my looking at the jQuery examples.

```
$(".check_SystemName").live("click", function(){
  var thisClicked = $(this);
  thisClicked.parent().children('.SystemNameStatus').text('found it');
});
```

Comment: The list is a dynamically created list.  Once the Save button (not shown here) is clicked, then the systemnames will be inserted into a database where they will receive a unique ID.  For this project, ID's are not an option, unfortunately (not my choice).  :(

Comment: If it ain't unique, you're up the crique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dancrumb is very right.  the code below May still work, but there is no way I would purposefully duplicate IDs.

```
$(".check_SystemName").live("click", function(){
var thisClicked = $(this);
thisClicked.closest("tr").find('.SystemNameStatus').text('found it');
});
```

Once you fix your id's, or just get rid of them as they're broken and can't be trusted in JavaScript as is, here is what my small changes did.  You were close, .parent() only goes one layer up the Dom, specifically to the `<td>`  .parents("tr") may find a bunch of `<tr>`s if you are in a nested table.  .closest("tr") finds the closest parent in the dom.  the original .children() call only went one layer deep, to the `<td>`s again.  .find("") will continue down the descendants.

Comment: I thought of using closest but not with the TR tag.  Can you explain why made you use closest with TR?  I was thinking closest("DIV") but it didn't work.

Comment: This question is just for my knowledge then...
if this table had multiple rows, would you still have used the same solution or would you have had to use something different than closest()?

Comment: @dlackey technically, the Div you want is not an ancestor of $(this), it's an uncle.  thisClicked.parent().siblings('.SystemNameStatus') could work to.

Comment: @dlackey i prefer .closest() as it allows a measure of freedom in case the HTML changes on you.  same reason for .find().

Answer (score 2):

ID is, by definition, supposed to be unique.  If it isn't then all bets are off regarding which element you'll get back when the browser runs getElementById (which is what jQuery does behind the scenes).

If you need several elements to share the same styling or be considered part of a group for other reasons then you should be using class instead, and then give the unique ID to the element you actually want to select.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have problems here. `id` attributes are required to be unique. If they are not, you don't have a valid DOM and all bets are off. You certainly can't rely on the behaviour of the standard frameworks as they have an expectation that the DOM will follow certain rules... eg `id`s being unique.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to remove the ID="" references altogether for this page?

Comment: Not necessarily; using element IDs can make styling and Javascript enhancement much simpler. If you're creating a table in a loop, it's simple to generate a unique id: just increment the id once per pass through the loop.